# How to implement Google StreetView Using Google CardBoard SDK?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-street-view, google-cardboard

We are planning to create Google Cardboard experience for Google StreetView.  Google has exposed Google Streetview API to fetch images based on the location and angle. If I use this API, I need to stitch the images based on the User head movement.  User can watch the object in 360 degree horizontally and 180 degree vertically.  How do I implement this based on the StreetView API and How often I need to make the request and what is the best way to combine the images. Is there is any way we can use the "com.google.android.gms.maps.StreetViewPanoramaView" directly inside the com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.CardboardView ?.. Thanks in Advance..

Comment: any success on this? trying to build similar thing but can't find any street view vr api

Comment: Google Streetview ended cardboard view on Google Maps app. Do you know if someone can develop using Google Maps API to create the VR experience for cardboard using Streetview images' source?

Answer (score 2):

Nice idea and good luck with that. However for your question you can use any panorama stitching library to stitch all the images together and create a view.
Following is a popular library but I afraid its paid.

http://www.cloudburstresearch.com/image-stitching-sdk/

For some awesome open source stuff here it is however I am not sure about the performance
https://code.google.com/p/android-opencv-panorama/

https://www.dermandar.com/SDK/

Hope this help!